# Is a facet_grid/wrap required to group boxplots by a variable other than used for fill/colour?

Tags: r, ggplot2, boxplot

I've run two experiments, some replicating the conditions of a previous set. I have a column for the unique lot ID as well as another column containing the ID from experiment 1 which the lots from experiment 2 replicates. Here's some example data stored like this:

```
test <- data.frame(var1=c(rep("A",4), rep("B",4), rep("C",4), rep("D",4)),
                   var2=rep(c(rep("A",4), rep("B",4)),2),
                   value=runif(16,1,5))
```

Here's my ggplot code:

```
ggplot(test, aes(x=var1, y=value, fill=var2)) + geom_boxplot()
```

This gives me the lot IDs arranged according to `var1`'s factor order.

[image]

I'd like the A's from `var2` side by side and the B's from `var2` side by side. Is the only way to do this by using `facet_grid` or `facet_wrap`?

```
 ggplot(test, aes(x=var1, y=value, fill=var2)) + geom_boxplot() +
        facet_grid(. ~ var2, scales="free_x")
```

[image]

I tried adding `group=var2` but that gives me overlapping and very wide boxplots, which I also don't understand:

```
ggplot(test, aes(x=var1, y=value, group=var2, fill=var2)) + geom_boxplot()
Warning message:
position_dodge requires non-overlapping x intervals
```

[image]

I can use facetting; I'm mostly asking the question as I was surprised when I couldn't group  how I expected. I also looked in the examples for `geom_bar()` for more grouping approaches but it seems most people aren't grouping things this way.

Feel free to provide other input on how one might approach this. I'm simply looking to compare pairs of test results to make it easy to see whether the replicate matches the original trial.

Comment: My understanding is that group will be set be default according to the combinations of fill / colour / faceting etc, and perhaps setting it explicitly within the original call will over-rule this default setting.

Comment: @mnel: If I understand you, that's what I tried in the last example. `ggplot(test, aes(x=var1, y=value, group=var2, fill=var2)) + geom_boxplot()`. I used `group=var2` and got some sort of combined boxplot as a result.

Comment: No, you would have to have `group = interaction(var1, var2)` but the x axis will still be ordered alphabetically. Regardless, I've put two possible approaches in my answer below

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A cheats method using `interaction` and adjusting the `scale_x_discrete` labels

```
 ggplot(test, aes(x=interaction(var1,var2), y=value, fill=var2)) + 
  geom_boxplot() +
  scale_x_discrete(name = 'var1',breaks = c('A.A','C.A','B.B','D.B'), 
                   labels = c('A','C','B','D'))
```

[image]

**EDIT** Thanks to @Andrie's comments

Or you can create an appropriately ordered factor, **or (unordered) factor with levels specified in the correct order**.

- ggplot2 respects the order of the factor levels (whether in an `ordered` factor or not).
- R will order the levels a factor *lexicographically* by default, so for any other order, you will need to specify it.

.

```
library(plyr) # for arrange 
var1_order <- unique(as.character(arrange(test,var2)[['var1']]))

test$var1_order <- ordered(test$var1, levels = var1_order)
## or
test$var1_order_2 <- factor(test$var1, levels = var1_order)
## so that 
ggplot(test, aes(x=var1_order_2, y=value, fill=var2)) + 
 geom_boxplot() + 
 xlab('var1')
## or 
ggplot(test, aes(x=var1_order, y=value, fill=var2)) + 
 geom_boxplot() + 
 xlab('var1')
```

Will both give the same result

### EDIT -- Another approach

You could have your x axis as `var2` and fill by `var1`, which will order by `var2` then dodge and fill by `var1`

```
  ggplot(test, aes(x=var2,y=value)) + 
   geom_boxplot(aes(fill = var1))
```

[image]

Comment: The second route is interesting. I'm not familiar with ordered factors. If a variable is such, ggplot won't re-arrange the order according the fill grouping -- is that reading this right?

Comment: +1 Nice answer. Minor correction on your comment about sorting order. It's important to understand that `ggplot` doesn't do any sorting itself. Instead, it reports results in the order of the factor levels. By default, R sorts factors `lexicographically`, which is the order you end up with. If you want a different order, you can simply rearrange the factor levels, i.e. you don't need an ordered factor to achieve this.

Comment: Thanks @Andrie - I wasn't aware of the distinction between ordering factor levels and ordered factors.

Comment: I've added that to the answer

Comment: I'll take the answer :) Intuitively, I still think ggplot grouping should allow this and don't know that I entirely understand why it combines boxplot results at those factor levels instead of clustering them together... but your answer does what I want. After playing with `interaction`, that *is* what I'm looking to do in the end -- plot interactions between the various levels. And this is also what faceting does. In any case, thanks a lot of the answer and giving me some alternative methods to view the data!